# export data in html table format in ios7 and make email body

Tags: html, ios, email

I am new in iphone application development. In my application i am using two different `NSMutable` array's. Both have dictionary with 4 fields like name, address etc at each index. Now my problem is I want to export that data in HTML table format and make email body. So please, can any one help me.

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289195/sending-out-html-email-with-img-tag-from-an-iphone-app-using-mfmailcomposeviewco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example items are:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrItem = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"sam",@"name",@"london",@"address",nil], nil];
```

Now `create html string` like this :

```
NSString *strHTML =  @"<!DOCTYPE html>"
                     @"<html><body>"
                     @"<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\">"; //change width according to your requirement

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrItem) {
    NSString *strName = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *strAddress = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];
    strHTML = [strHTML stringByAppendingString:@"<tr>"];
    //add table column  value 
    strHTML = [strHTML stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",strName]];
    strHTML = [strHTML stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<td>%@</td>",strAddress]];
    strHTML = [strHTML stringByAppendingString:@"</tr>"];
}

strHTML = [strHTML stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"
                                            @"</body>"
                                            @"</html>"];
```

Use `hmtl string` in `MailcompserViewController` :

```
[controller setMessageBody:strHTML isHTML:YES];
```

**EDIT** : formatted

Answer (score 0):

```
MailcompserViewController *controller = [[MailcompserViewController alloc] init];//Allocating  mailComposer
NSString *eMailBody=@""; //Value for row
for (int i=0; i<[arrMailList count]; i++) { //Get all the row value
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
MailData *data = [arrMailList objectAtIndex:i]; //Get array value in NSObject class
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:data.date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy"]; //Date NSDateFormatter
NSString *strDate = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date];
NSString *numbers = [data.setName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]];
eMailBody = [eMailBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"<tr><td width=\"200px\">%@</td><td >%@</td><td >%@</td><td >%@</td><td>%@</td><td >%@</td></tr>",strDate,data.Name,data.email,data.address,data.phoneNumber];//Create row
        }
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><style>body{font-family:Helvetica;font-size:14px;}th{fontcolor:#ffffff;font-size:16px;font-weight:BOLD;}</style><body><table cellpadding=5px border=1px bordercolor=#000000><tr bgcolor=#cccccc><th width=200>Date</th><th>Workout Name</th><th>Excercise Name</th><th>Set</th><th>Weight</th><th>Reps</th>%@</table></body></html>",eMailBody]; //Add row in table view       
[controller setMessageBody:html isHTML:YES];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: you are also may be right but i want easy way. so thank you for giving me replay

Answer (score 0):

var str = "\n"

```
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<tr><th>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("Task")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</th>")

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<th>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("SpareParts")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</th>")

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<th>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("Labour")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</th></tr>\n")


    var i:Int=0
    for i=0;i<carImageList.count;i++
    {
       str=str.stringByAppendingString("<tr><td>")
       str=str.stringByAppendingString(carImageList[i] as! String)
       str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td>")

        str=str.stringByAppendingString("<td>")
        str=str.stringByAppendingString(carImageList[i] as! String)
        str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td>")

        str=str.stringByAppendingString("<td>")
        str=str.stringByAppendingString(carImageList[i] as! String)
        str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td></tr>\n")

    }

    //SubTotal
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<tr><td>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("Sub Total")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td>")

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<td>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("100")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td>")

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<td>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("100")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td></tr>\n")

   //Total

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<tr><td>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("Total")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td>")

    str=str.stringByAppendingString("<td colSpan='2'>")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("300")
    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</td></tr>\n")



    str=str.stringByAppendingString("</table></body></html>\n")
    NSLog("TEST %@",str)
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(str, isHTML: true)
```

Comment: Add this Line at the top: var str = "<HTML><body><table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>\n"