# Attaching an image to an email?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, attachment, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to to use MFMailComposeViewController to send an email, and I already have that set up, but I'm having trouble actually attaching an image, which is a screenshot, into the email.

Here's the line of code.

```
[composer addAttachmentData:image mimeType:image/png //png undeclared//fileName:@"GameOver Screenshot.png"]; //Incompatible Obj-C types 'struct UIImage *' expected 'struct NSData *' when passing argument 1 of .....//
```

image is the name of my UIImage screenshot. I'm not sure what to replace it with.

Thanks in advance for the help/assistance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first parameter to addAttachmentData is an NSData of the attachment.  If your `image` is a UIImage, then try this:

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[composer addAttachmentData:data 
                   mimeType:@"image/png" 
                   fileName:@"GameOver Screenshot.png"];
```