# iPhone : Problem while sending image and text in HTML formate using MFMailCompose

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am sending `HTML` in mail using MFMailCompose.

This `HTML` includes strings and images.

So when I use to send this mail, It is sending text only. It does not display any images.

How can I send my all `HTML` data So that images are shown in email ?

Comment: Relevant SO question: [`How to embed image in html in MFMailComposeViewController for iPhone`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239398/how-to-embed-image-in-html-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you cannot embed images into the HTML body of a message (though you can, of course, embed references to images located elsewhere on the net).  Images *attached* to the HTML message (using the mail composer's function for adding attachments) will generally (with most mail readers) be displayed following the message in a fairly "attractive" format.  (Note that you don't get this nice formatting if the message itself is not HTML.)

Answer (score 0):

I am working on doing the same thing, i.e. trying to embed an image into an email message.  I just came across the following post http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/embedding-images-in-outbound-email-using-cocoa-touch/ that looks promising.  I have not tried this yet but will do so later this week.  If  you try this yourself, let us know if it worked for you.