# image does not show in the E-mail body

Tags: iphone, html, mfmailcomposer

i am trying to send an html page which includes image and text. The problem is that image in not shown when i send it. what could be the solution for it ? 
thaks in advance..

My code is :

```
[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:@"ShowerDoorsQuotation.pdf"];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body><img  src='ShowerDoors/ShowerDoors/logo.png' width='150px' height='150px'/>
  </body>
  </html>"];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Comment: can we have more information?

Comment: in the current mail system, mail provider like gmail, yahoo has blocked the image. the image will be show on click of display image. you cann't change it.

Comment: ya. but it does not show me the image even in the simulator.

Comment: show the code that you are implementing..

Comment: thanks. i have reduced my question. now give me the answer.

Comment: why you have tagged this question for C# ??

Comment: i have not tagged the C#. kay has tagged it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are put the image URL like this `src='ShowerDoors/ShowerDoors/logo.png'` 
Change to the FULL URL like `http://www.example.com/ShowerDoors/ShowerDoors/logo.png`, It may be works...

Answer (score 1):

Currently, You can not send local images using MEMailComposer. Hope apple will include this feature in future.

Rather you can give link of image which are on your server. And then you will able to see images in mail.

Or [as paulheyer writes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216735/19679):

> You can have inline images in HTML but you have to encode the
>   attachments data using base64 encoding. This leads to problems with
>   some email clients e.g. Gmail. Please find a detailed discussion on
>   this issue here: [How to add an UIImage in MailComposer Sheet of
>   MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527351/how-to-add-an-uiimage-in-mailcomposer-sheet-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ip)

Or

[How to embed image in html in MFMailComposeViewController for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239398/how-to-embed-image-in-html-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-for-iphone)

Comment: Do not plagiarize language from other people's answers without providing proper attribution. I've edited your answer to credit paulheyer for the words of his you copied.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to send html in email you must include absolute urls, not relative.