# how to put an image on the top of an email sent with MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

I need some help! :)

I am trying to put a header png image in a email using MFMailComposeViewController
I understood that attaching an image to the email will place the image after the body text so i converted the image to Base64 and put it as html (img src=…).
the thing is that i also need to make this image a link to a website i imagine that it is by using (a href…).
but i manage to see the header in the mail composer on my ipad but after sending it by mail it comes to the email with no header or with only the name of the image in an empty box :(

i am wasting a lot of time on that. does somebody know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: image path should be web path whenever u send it through html. Is this present in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be just what you're looking for:

[How to add an UIImage in MailComposer Sheet of MFMailComposeViewController in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527351/how-to-add-an-uiimage-in-mailcomposer-sheet-of-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-iph)