# Get Content ID from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uiimage, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I was searching how to add image to message body and found a lot of questions that it's impossible do it using MIME and add image to message body using standart MFMailComposeViewController.

Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527833/456471

But I know the app in appstore: http://itunes.apple.com/app/emoji-free/id444304133

This app using standart mail client:

```
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (9B206)
```

and MIME:

```
  --Apple-Mail-FEB04051-AF80-474D-BC69-1A83514A008C
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset=utf-8

<html><head></head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div></div><div><br><a href="http://itunes.apple.com/app/emoji-free/id444304133?partnerId=30&amp;siteID=LjQr0YBXPSs">Brought to you by the Emoji app</a></div><div><br><br><img src="cid:5A2B705A-7ACB-438B-996F-FAEA8E92B28B" id="5A2B705A-7ACB-438B-996F-FAEA8E92B28B"></div><div><br><br>Best regards<div>Danil</div></div></body></html>
--Apple-Mail-FEB04051-AF80-474D-BC69-1A83514A008C
Content-Disposition: inline;
    filename=emoji.png
Content-Id: <5A2B705A-7ACB-438B-996F-FAEA8E92B28B>
Content-Type: image/png;
    name=emoji.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Any suggestion how it can be?

Comment: did you figure this one out? i am facing the same problem at the moment