# Get UIImage in Mail Body using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to setup a mail to be sent from my Swift App. I am seeking to embed an image inside the HTML of my mail (not as attachment).

Is there a way to do that from my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here helped me. Needed to do a few modifications but this worked for me!

[How to add a image in email body using MFMailComposeViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210571/how-to-add-a-image-in-email-body-using-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)