# Create PDF from UIWebview with subview in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, pdf-generation, subview, uigraphicscontext

I viewed all type of document in UIWebview. After i will add some text and image in sub view of uiwebview . After i want to export pdf. I tried to below source to export but subview content not added in pdf. So please help me how to write with subview content in objective c

```
NSData *pdfFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webView.request.URL];

[pdfFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813005/creating-pdf-file-from-uiwebview)

Comment: @AlexanderW how its possible ?