# iOS create pdf from UIWebview content

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

In my app for iOS i need to create a pdf document from my webview content. I watched these posts: [Creating PDF file from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813005/creating-pdf-file-from-uiwebview) and https://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/making-a-pdf-from-a-uiwebview/

I wonder if there is a simpler way to do it. For example for my project for Mac i use this:

```
NSData *pdf = [[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] dataWithPDFInsideRect:[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView].frame];
PDFDocument *doc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithData:pdf];
```

Is there any simple way to do this in iOS?

Which is the best option to obtain best quality pdf document from a webview content?

Comment: refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813005/creating-pdf-file-from-uiwebview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a method that allows this directly via the SDK like there is on Mac however you may wish to take a look at [BNHtmlPdfKit](https://github.com/brentnycum/BNHtmlPdfKit) which allows you to save the contents of URLs, web views and also html strings as PDFs.

For example, as follows:

```
self.htmlPdfKit = [BNHtmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itsbrent.net"] toFile:@"...itsbrent.pdf" pageSize:BNPageSizeA6 success:^(NSString *pdfFileName) {
    NSLog(@"Done");
} failure:^(NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"Failure");
}];
```

It makes use of a custom `UIPrintPageRenderer` which overrides `paperRect` and `printableRect` thus causing the `UIPrintFormatter` to return a pageCount as well as render the document.

Answer (score 1):

I found good answer by AnderCover at
"[Creating PDF file from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813005/creating-pdf-file-from-uiwebview)" 
also it's not using any third party api. To create pdf from webview.

Hope it help's you.